# Multithreaded web scraping application

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, request, electron, child-process

I am developing an electron application for some web scraping tasks and have trouble deciding on how to handle the tasks while maximizing efficiency.

I have looked into different libraries such as cluster but it seems to be quite limited in functionality (one file for master and worker). I am not sure if child_process is the best choice either since I would need to fork a lot of tasks (up to 100) and as I understood that would take up a lot of resources.

Any suggestions on what to use for IO intensive but not too CPU intensive tasks with which I ideally don't have to handle the process "distribution" myself?

Comment: Are you coming from Python? Node IO is already asynchronous, you don't have to fork or do anything crazy.

Comment: please search here on stackoverflow for multithreading javascript....you will find many answers....